# How To Create Sequential File Names In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a script that will create sequential file names for images in a directory with leading zeros. The current code I'm trying to use is:

```
####Take a picture.
filename='/home/pi/pictures/'print 'img_{0:05d}'.format(i)'.jpg'
self.shoot(filename=filename)
```

I'm getting a syntax error when running seen here below.
http://prnt.sc/dhpf51

Comment: The print is outside the quotes and there is no connector to the string before it.  And there's no need to put print in there at all. The rest is fine.

Comment: `'../pictures/img_{0:05d}.jpg'.format(i)`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots (or links to screenshots) of text, paste the actual text into your question; you can use a code block to preserve formatting. See [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the screenshot,

```
filename='/home/pi/pictures/'print 'img_{0:05d}'.format(i)'.jpg'
```

is not correct syntaxt, you placed the `print` keyword between format string,
you can just use `format` for creating the path string.

```
filename='/home/pi/pictures/img_{0:05d}.jpg'.format(i)
```